# Make hyperlinks to lines in files of grep output

Tags: pycharm

Sometimes I use `grep` in the PyCharm terminal, since PyCharm search does not suit my needs.

Is there a way to make the output of grep in a way that PyCharm creates hyperlinks to the found lines, so that I can go to the line via a click on the link?

```
find abc/ -name '*.py' -mtime -3 |xargs grep -P 'assign.*date'
abc/institution.py:  assignment = slot.assignment.order_by('-date')[0]
abc/apl/views.py:    already_sent_qs = qs.filter(assignment__date...
abc/apl/views.py:    obj.assignment.all().update(info_mail_sent_date...
```

Example: I want to go to the first match:

`assignment = slot.assignment.order_by('-date')[0]` in file `abc/admin/institution.py`

Comment: I don't know a solution to your question, but are you aware you can do regex searches in PyCharm?

Comment: @nanotek yes, I know that PyCharm supports regex searches. But sometimes I want a combination of find+grep.

Comment: Obviously `find` and `grep` are large tools, and I'm guessing you're wanting full capabilities which I don't know how to do. I'll note that your simple use case of `find` can be done by changing the `File Mask` and changing `Scope` in your search though. You can search a `Module`, `Directory`, `Custom Patterns` etc. Obviously this isn't what you asked for, but might get you part of what you want without a full solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like this is a highly requested feature in [this ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-154439), started 6 years ago. Comments from jetbrains developers suggest when they do make the update it would be available for all tools.

If you have a team with paid licenses I'd suggest voting on tickets you'd like to see

Answer (score 0):

Until I can get hands on a working version, I made a bash function for this:

```
pg () {
    grep --line-number --recursive --with-filename "$@" | sed -re 's%^([^:]+):([0-9]+):\s+%File "'$PWD'/\1", line \2\n\t%
}
```

Disclaimer: only works for python files ...

I've seen someone made a similar one, and shared it on https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2590127